# Can I get a value from std::map without crashing if the key doesn't exist?

Tags: c++

I have C++ code like this:

```
if(rtstructure.find(varName) != rtstructure.end()) {
    rtdef = rtstructure[varName];
}
```

where rtstructure is std::map with std::string for the key.
This code works but it seems like a waste to make it search twice for the same key. If I omit the if case around the assignment, the program crashes if varName points to a key that doesn't exist.

Can I in a single map operation look up a key in a std::map and get its value if it exists, without crashing if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Your program shouldn't usually crash. Do you use `map<K,V*>` by any chance? Also note that `map::find` returns an iterator, you can happily use the `value` notion of the iterator (`second`)

Comment: Yes the map is std::map<std::string, rtobject_t*> rtstructure;
where rtobject_t is a struct.

Comment: So apparently, the [] operator returns a new uninitialized pointer if referring to a member that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) give you a `std::map<>::iterator` that holds/point to `std::pair<>`. The iterator can be saved and reused (given that you did not do anything to invalidate it such as `erase`).

```
// i don't know the type of rtstructure so i use auto
// you can replace it to the correct type if C++11 is not available
auto it = rtstructure.find(varName); 
if(it != rtstructure.end()) {
    rtdef = it->second;
}
```